# google map application not open in blackberry storm 2

Tags: google-maps, blackberry, blackberry-storm

i have storm 2 and i downloaded good map application from this url [click here](http://m.google.com/maps)

download successful but . in device option>application(third party) i can see Google map app but in download folder i cant see this application  .
how can i open this application ? application is already installed when i tried to second time install .

Give me suggetion .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find "Google maps" in "Applications" folder. It is not in "Downloads" folder, it was installed in "Applications" folder.

Comment: Thanx after rrboot i got it in application folder . but when i open this application i got this error : "network unavailable .this application requires a data connection.and some blackberry devices require reconfiguration to work properly ."

Comment: check you wifi and/or apn settings if you don't have bis